# Why are jsp:include pages with get parameters marked as error in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

My collegues are using netbeans, for which the following validates fine:

```
<jsp:include page="/somepage.jsp?parameter=value"/>
```

Yet in eclipse I get

> Fragment was not found at the selected path

This is to do with adding parameters, as the following validates fine:

```
<jsp:include page="/somepage.jsp"/>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing Parameters to Another JSP Page
An include action (see Including a File in a JSP Page) executes the included JSP page and appends the generated output onto its own output stream. Request parameters parsed from the URL's query string are available not only to the main JSP page but to all included JSP pages as well. It is possible to temporarily override a request parameter or to temporarily introduce a new request parameter when calling a JSP page. This is done by using the jsp:param action.

In this example, param1 is specified in the query string and is automatically made available to the callee JSP page. param2 is also specified in the query string but is overridden by the caller. Notice that param2 reverts to its original value after the call. param3 is a new request parameter created by the caller. Notice that param3 is only available to the callee and when the callee returns, param3 no longer exists. Here is the caller JSP page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<jsp:include page="callee.jsp" />
   <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2" />
   <jsp:param name="param3" value="value3" />
</jsp:include>

Caller:
param1: <%= request.getParameter("param1") %>
param2: <%= request.getParameter("param2") %>
param3: <%= request.getParameter("param3") %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSP page being called:

Callee:

```
param1: <%= request.getParameter("param1") %>
param2: <%= request.getParameter("param2") %>
param3: <%= request.getParameter("param3") %>
```

If the example is called with the URL:

```
http://hostname.com?param1=a&param2=b
```

the output would be:

Callee:

param1: a

param2: value2

param3: value3

Caller:

param1: a

param2: b

param3: null

Visit http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/caller.jsp.html

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the OP's question. If it does, it's not clear to me. He's asking about an eclipse error, which is not even mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should have use `<jsp:param>` to pass request parameters.

```
<jsp:include page="/somepage.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="parameter1" value="value1"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse thinks that the name of the file being included is "somepage.jsp?parameter=value", which of course doesn't exist. It validates fine in NetBeans because whatever mechanism it uses to parse/validate the path is smarter than Eclipse's.

The error in Eclipse is a false-positive (assuming "somepage.jsp" truly does exist in the expected location) because the JSP compiler will interpret the path correctly and include "parameter=value" as a parameter into the included JSP, accessible by:

`${param.parameter}` or `${param['parameter']}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the parameter in url then disable the "JSP Syntax Validator " in eclipse.

Project right click -> Properties -> Validation

[image]

Make sure to enable project specific setting, The checkbox above. Otherwise it will take default setting.